# Nodejs can't export function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a generic instance of an api instance to keep my code DRY. Running into an issue exporting the function:

```
TypeError: request is not a function
```

index.js

```
var express   = require('express'),
    app       = express();
const axios     = require("axios");
const request = require("./request");


app.get("/api", (req, res) => {
  request({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1'
  }).then((resp) => {
    console.log(resp);
  })
});


app.listen(3000);
```

request.js

```
const axios     = require("axios");

/**
 * Create an Axios Client with defaults
*/
const client = axios.create({
//  baseURL: constants.api.url
});



/**
 * Request Wrapper with default success/error actions
 */
 module.exports.request = function(options) {
  const onSuccess = function(response) {
    console.debug('Request Successful!', response);
    return response.data;
  }

  const onError = function(error) {
    console.error('Request Failed:', error.config);

    if (error.response) {
      // Request was made but server responded with something
      // other than 2xx
      console.error('Status:',  error.response.status);
      console.error('Data:',    error.response.data);
      console.error('Headers:', error.response.headers);

    } else {
      // Something else happened while setting up the request
      // triggered the error
      console.error('Error Message:', error.message);
    }

    return Promise.reject(error.response || error.message);
  }

  return client(options)
            .then(onSuccess)
            .catch(onError);
}
```

The original code was written with es6 but I guess node doesnt work well so I would like to convert the above function so that node can run it.

Comment: Node supports ES6.  You may need to upgrade Node to a more-recent version.

Comment: `request` in an object in index.js. You are exporting using `module.exports.request = fx()`. To export a single function use `module.exports = fx()`

Comment: Since you are exporting an object with a `request` property, and not the `request` function itself, I'm pretty sure your import syntax should be `const request = require("./request").request;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module.exports.request = ...
```

You just exported an object with a `request` function.  That object is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

To do this ES6 style in node you'll need to define the methods as consts:

`const onSuccess(response) => {
    ...
    }
    const onError(error) => {
    ...
    }`

Then `export {onSuccess, onError}`
If ES6 doesn't work in your node project install babel.